# Is there something stuck my app before Application is initialized?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, dagger-hilt

I am using Jetpack Compose. When I open my app, it displays a blank page with a status bar in primary color before my first activity shows up, for some reasons I can't post code snippets here please check screenshots below:

[I have logs in attachBaseContext() and onCreate of my Application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwO5n.jpg)

[I have log in onCreate() of my unique Activity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ach0b.jpg)

My first activity displays all the contents correctly, but as you can see that no log prints out from either Application or my first Activity in Logcat when the confused page shows up(See the 2nd screenshot). How did this happen? Can I somehow fix this issue?

BTW I am also using Hilt as injection in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to start a Jetpack Compose project from scratch is using an `Empty Compose Project` from File>New Project. It will prepare a basic project with all the necessary dependencies and a minimal working screen, plus all what is needed to theme your project.

Few suggestions to address your issue:

- try to use `Log` class to show logs in the Logcat:

`Log.d("TAG","Message")`

- From what we can see your display should show `UiPage()`, but this method is only defined as a prototype but has no content. Try using:

```
@Composable
fun UiPage(){
Text("MyPage")
}
```

In general, when you write a post is more efficient (and readable) post your code snippets using specific formatting. Use screenshots just to display graphics.

Comment: Hi,@Frax, thanks for your comment, and sorry for I didn't make my question very clear. Yes, the UiPage() in screenshot is a prototype and I did implement it in a child Activity, and the content displayed correctly as what I've made. What makes me struggled is an unexpected page shows up between the launcher of the phone and the first Activity of my app(see the 2nd screenshot), and with this weird page shows up neither onCreate() functions from Application and my first activity are invoked.

Comment: And my code snippets contains the name of my company, that's the reason that  I can't post my code for this issue. Sorry.